# Change Widget that display posts from categories to tags

Tags: widgets, tags

I have a theme with a widget that display posts from category and I wanna change it to posts from tags if it s possible.

Here is the code :

```
// NewsInPictures Widget
class NewsInPictures extends WP_Widget
{
    function NewsInPictures(){
    $widget_ops = array('description' => 'Shows your latest posts presented with their images.');
    $control_ops = array('width' => 200, 'height' => 300);
    parent::__construct(false,$name='[Voxis] News in pictures',$widget_ops,$control_ops);
    }

  /* Displays the Widget in the front-end */
    function widget($args, $instance){
    extract($args);

    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title']);
    $number_posts = $instance['number_posts'];
    $categories = $instance['categories'];

    echo $before_widget; 

    if ( $title != '' )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

    echo '
    <div class="photo-list">';
    $args = array();
    if(!empty($categories) )
        $args['category__in'] = $categories;
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $number_posts != 0 ? $number_posts : 20;
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); global $post; ?>
        <div class='photo'>
            <?php 
            if(has_post_thumbnail() ) 
                $thumb = aq_resize(wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ), 112, 112, true);
            else
                $thumb = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/missing_56.png';
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php the_title();?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" width="112px" height="112px" />
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php 
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); 
    echo '</div>';

    echo $after_widget;
  }

  /*Saves the settings. */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
    $instance =  array();
    $instance['title'] = esc_attr($new_instance['title']);
    $instance['number_posts'] = (int)$new_instance['number_posts'];
    $instance['categories'] = $new_instance['categories'];

    return $instance;
  }

  /*Creates the form for the widget in the back-end. */
    function form($instance){
    //Defaults
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array('number_posts'=> 5, 'title' => '', 'categories' => array() ) );

    $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
    $number_posts = (int) $instance['number_posts'];
    $categories = (array) $instance['categories'];

    echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '">' . 'Title: ' . '</label><input id="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('title') . '" value="'. esc_textarea($title)  . '" /></p>';
    echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('number_posts') . '">' . 'Number of posts: ' . '</label><input id="' . $this->get_field_id('number_posts') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('number_posts') . '" value="'. esc_textarea($number_posts)  . '" /></p>';
    $cats = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
    ?>
    <p>
        <label>Categories to include: </label> <br />
        <?php foreach( $cats as $category ) { ?>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('categories'); ?>[]" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"  <?php if(in_array( $category->cat_ID, $categories ) ) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?> /> 
                <?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>
            </label> <br />
        <?php } ?>
    </p> 
    <?php
  }

}// end NewsInPictures class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main changes needed in order to use tags instead of categories would be:

In section one, change...

```
$args['category__in'] = $categories;
```

to

```
$args['tag__in'] = $categories;
```

And in the second section, change the cats loop:

```
$title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
$number_posts = (int) $instance['number_posts'];
$categories = (array) $instance['categories'];

echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '">' . 'Title: ' . '</label><input id="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('title') . '" value="'. esc_textarea($title)  . '" /></p>';
echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('number_posts') . '">' . 'Number of posts: ' . '</label><input id="' . $this->get_field_id('number_posts') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('number_posts') . '" value="'. esc_textarea($number_posts)  . '" /></p>';
$tags = get_tags('hide_empty=0');
?>
<p>
   <label>Tags to include: </label> <br />
   <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('categories'); ?>[]" value="<?php echo $tag->term_id; ?>"  <?php if(in_array( $tag->term_id, $categories ) ) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?> /> 
         <?php echo $tag->name; ?>
      </label> <br />
   <?php } ?>
</p> 
<?php
```

Obviously, you can rename the variables and instance variables if wanted to reflect that you are now using tags instead of categories, but the changes I noted above will make it work properly.

Comment: i used the code above and i faced 1 probléme in the back office widget when i choose 1 tag to use and save all the tags r checked i cant check only 1 tag. thanks for help

Comment: `$tag->term_ID` should be `$tag->term_id`